# displaying a label output in print out rather than web page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to display the current date and time when the user clicks on the print button. I dont want to see the date and time on my web page. This is the content that I want to print:

```
<div class="box" id="dvContents">
    this is the content, I want to print
   <div id="CalculateGrid" style="margin-top: 60px">
    <asp:Label ID="lblDateTime" runat="server" Style="margin-left: 25%; display: none;" />
   </div>
 </div>
```

On the click of my asp button, I am calling a Javascript function. Below is the button and javascript function:

```
 <asp:LinkButton  ID="print"  runat="server" OnClientClick="PrintDiv();">Print</asp:LinkButton>
```

Below is the javascript function:

```
<script>


    function PrintDiv() {
            document.getElementById('<%=lblDateTime.ClientID %>').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('<%=lblDateTime.ClientID %>').innerHTML = new Date().toLocaleString();
            var contents = document.getElementById("dvContents").innerHTML;
            
            var frame1 = document.createElement('iframe');
            frame1.name = "frame1";
            frame1.style.position = "absolute";
            frame1.style.top = "-1000000px";
            document.body.appendChild(frame1);
            var frameDoc = (frame1.contentWindow) ? frame1.contentWindow : (frame1.contentDocument.document) ? frame1.contentDocument.document : frame1.contentDocument;
            frameDoc.document.open();
            frameDoc.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');
            frameDoc.document.write('</head><body>');
            frameDoc.document.write(contents);
            frameDoc.document.write('</body></html>');
            frameDoc.document.close();
            setTimeout(function () {
                window.frames["frame1"].focus();
                window.frames["frame1"].print();
                document.body.removeChild(frame1);
            }, 500);
           
            return false;
        }
       
    
    </script>
```

In the first two lines of the javascript function, I am trying to display date and time:

```
 document.getElementById('<%=lblDateTime.ClientID %>').style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById('<%=lblDateTime.ClientID %>').innerHTML = new Date().toLocaleString();
```

so that they can appear in the printout, but as soon as I click on the print button, the date and time appear on the web page too. I don't want to see the date and time on my web page, I just want to see the date and time on my printout. I am not sure what am I doing wrong.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i do an experiment here

```js
function PrintDiv() {
            document.getElementById('lblDateTime').style.opacity = "0";
            document.getElementById('lblDateTime').innerHTML = new Date().toLocaleString();
        
            var contents2 = document.getElementById("dvContents");
          
            var frame1 = document.createElement('iframe');            
            var contents = document.getElementById("dvContents").innerHTML;
            
            frame1.name = "frame1";
            frame1.style.position = "absolute";
            frame1.style.top = "-1000000px";
            document.body.appendChild(frame1);
            var frameDoc = (frame1.contentWindow) ? frame1.contentWindow : (frame1.contentDocument.document) ? frame1.contentDocument.document : frame1.contentDocument;
            frameDoc.document.open();
            frameDoc.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');
            
            frameDoc.document.write('<style>@media print{ #lblDateTime { opacity:1!important}  }</style>');
            
            frameDoc.document.write('</head><body>');
            
            frameDoc.document.write(contents);               
            frameDoc.document.write('</body></html>');
            frameDoc.document.close();
            setTimeout(function () {
                window.frames["frame1"].focus();
                window.frames["frame1"].print();
               document.body.removeChild(frame1);
            }, 500);
           
            return false;
        }
```

```html
<div class="box" id="dvContents">
    this is the content, I want to print
   <div id="CalculateGrid" style="margin-top: 60px">
   <div id="lblDateTime" style="opacity:0;display:inline;" ></div>
   </div>

 </div>
 


<button  id="print"  runat="server" onclick="PrintDiv();">Print</button>
```

try on your browser directly due to can't print here, hope it will helps.

Comment: I put the above code in the application and when I am clicking on the print, its not printing anything. I dont even see the print pop up window

Comment: What the message do you get on console?

Comment: can try this ?
https://jsfiddle.net/trysetyoutomo/L1pnx2g6/2/

Comment: I don't get any message on the console. I tried one more time. when I click on the print button, it just flickers and nothing happens. I am trying this on google chrome.